# How to prove the estimators and residuals of regression models are identical or different?

Tags: regression, econometrics

Original equation is as below: $$y = X_1\beta_1 + X_2\beta_2 + u $$
I have to compare the estimator $\hat\beta_2$ and residuals $\hat u$ with the below different regression models:

$$y = X_2\beta_2 + v$$ $$P_xy = X_1\beta_1 + X_2\beta_2 + v$$ 
$${M_{x_1}}y = X_2\beta_2 + v$$ 
$${M_{x_1}}y = X_1\beta_1 + {M_{x_1}}X_2\beta_2 +v$$

Here, $P_x = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the projection matrix and $M_x = I - P_x$ is the annihilator matrix. The subscription of these matrices indicate which subspace of regressor it is projecting or annihilating (i.e. $M_{x_1} = I - P_{x_1} = I - X_1({X_1}{'}{X_1})^{-1}X_1'$). Also, the residual $v$ is to differenciating from the original residuals $u$, pointing out the possibility that the residuals can be different in these regression models.

This is one of Davidson's questions that I want to work on and understand. 
I know that the first three equations will result in different estimators and residuals, but I was wondering how I can show it mathematically to prove that they are not identical.

For the last equation, would it be the same estimator by FWL theorem? 
Could anyone help me with this question?

Comment: What does "FWL" mean?  What do the symbols "$M$" and "$P$" stand for? Note that to show different estimators and residuals are possible, it suffices to exhibit actual datasets in which the estimators or residuals differ.  Will you be using least squares estimators or something else (and if so, what)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was referring FWL to Frisch Waugh Lovell Theorem, and $P_x = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and $M_x = I - P_x$. What I understand is that $P_x$ is the projection matrix that will result $P_x y = \hat y$, and $M_x y = \hat u$. Here, the question is asking to get the least square estimators and compare with the other regression models that I stated. I hope this helps..!

Comment: Yes, it helps, thank you. That notation is not standard and must be explained.  It's crucial that you include those explanations in an edit to the question itself--not everyone reads comments and comments can disappear without notice for various reasons. When you make those changes, consider amplifying your explanations, because there is an inherent confusion between the meanings of "$u$" and "$v$" that you need to clear up. In particular, whenever you use "$P$" or "$M$" you must indicate which model they refer to.  The subscripts "$x$" and "$x_1$" are particularly mysterious in that regard.

Comment: I have added additional explanation in the post as well! Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Thank you--it's pretty clear now.  But in the second model I still don't get what "$P_x$" is intended to mean.  What is "$X$"?  It wouldn't make any sense for it to refer to the full model matrix.

Comment: Algebraically, $P_x$ performs an orthogonal projection onto a given subspace. In this case from my understanding, If we premultiply $y$ by $P_x$, it projects the information in $y$ onto the subspace of $X$, resulting the $X\hat\beta$, which is the fitted value of $y$. Here, $X$ is the $n$ by $k$ matrix of regressors, and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the partitioned matrix from $X$. Hope this helps..!